# Geography Point in C# POCO (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, spatial, poco

I'm writing a Web API (.Net Core) with Entity Framework Core.

I would like to place my models in a POCO libraries. But I have a problem with the Geography fields. With EF Core, I saw that the Geography fields were managed by the NetTopologySuite library. But how to do it in a POCO? If I reference NetTopologySuite, that means referencing EF Core as well.

**Is it possible to manage the geography fields for use with EF Core in a POCO library?**

Example:

```
public partial class Adresses
{
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }

    public Point Localisation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to save it to your database the way as the properties set by NetTopologySuite?

Comment: @JericCruz  I want that my Location field to be stored in a database (SQL Server) with the Geography type. It works with NetTopologySuite but I don't see how to place my model in a POCO. In a POCO, I cannot reference NetTopologySuite. 
So I cannot declare my Location field of type Point.

Comment: @StevenPF How about just referencing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types nuget package  and use the type directly from that?

Comment: @Tintow : Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is not fully compatible with .Net Core / .Net Standard. But, there are Microsoft.Spatial and System.Spatial. But do these two libraries work with EF Core?